# Tagging a form field #myFormField vs #myFormField="ngModel"

Tags: angular, forms, angular-ngmodel

Could somebody point out please:

**What exactly happens/changes when a `#myFormField` is extended to `#myFormField="ngModel"`?** And what is the name of these notations?

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('inputPhoneNumber') viewChildPhoneNumber: number;
  phoneNumber: number;
}
```

**Case 1: `#inputPhoneNumber` with output below**

```
<p> Input Field</p>

<input 
class="form-control" 
type="text" 
[(ngModel)]="phoneNumber"
pattern="[\d]*" 
#inputPhoneNumber
required
/>
<div *ngIf="inputPhoneNumber.errors?.pattern"> 
  <b>Phone number must only contain digits</b>
</div>

<div>Two Way Binding: <b>{{phoneNumber}}</b></div>
<div>ViewChild: <b>{{viewChildPhoneNumber.nativeElement.value}}</b></div>
<div>#inputPhoneNumber: <b>{{inputPhoneNumber.value}}</b></div>
```

[image: Case 1 Output (<code>#inputPhoneNumber</code>)]

**Case 2 Output - Extending same code to `#inputPhoneNumber="ngModel"`**
[image: Case 2 Output]

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qyw1dk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Well, the explanation to what the difference is between the two syntaxes can be read here [Take Advantage Of The exportAs Property](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26). Why your specific code isn't working is because the template errors out on your `{{viewChildPhoneNumber.nativeElement.value}}`. Remove that and it should work as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Just supplying an `input` tag with a template variable, `#inputPhoneNumber` will assign the JavaScript Object Representation of that `HTMLElement` to the template variable.

Try it with this:

```
<p> Input Field - With Just Template Varaible:</p>

<input 
  class="form-control" 
  type="text" 
  [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber"
  pattern="[\d]*" 
  #first
  required
  />

<div *ngIf="first.errors?.pattern"> 
  Phone number must only contain digits
</div>

<div>Two Way Binding: {{phoneNumber}}</div>
<div>ViewChild Native Element: {{viewChildFirst?.nativeElement | json}}</div>
<div>ViewChild Control: {{viewChildFirst.control | json}}</div>
<div>#first: {{first?.value}}</div>
```

And in the Component Class:

```
@ViewChild('first') viewChildFirst;
```

As it is quite apparent, `viewChildFirst.control` will not be defined in this case.

---

But assigning `ngModel` to the template variable will assign the [**`FormControl`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) representation of that HTML Element to the template variable.

Try it with this:

```
<p> Input Field - With Template And ngModel assigned</p>

<input 
  class="form-control" 
  type="text" 
  [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber"
  pattern="[\d]*" 
  #second="ngModel"
  required
  />

<div *ngIf="second.errors?.pattern"> 
  Phone number must only contain digits
</div>

<div>Two Way Binding: {{phoneNumber}}</div>
<div>ViewChild Native Element: {{viewChildSecond?.nativeElement}}</div>
<div>ViewChild Conttrol: {{viewChildSecond.control | json}}</div>
<div>#second: {{second?.value}}</div>

<hr>
```

And in the Component Class:

```
@ViewChild('second') viewChildSecond;
```

This time around, `viewChildSecond?.nativeElement` would not be defined but `viewChildSecond.control` would be.

---

> You can check it out by exactly printing out the template variable as I've done above. Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-variable-vs-template-variable-assigned-ngmodel?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.